Similar to "Echo All commands" in Blender?
Is there a way to see which python codes or methods run when I press a hotkey ?
eg I Press "ö" and some action happens. and I don't know what it is.
(also Preferences > KeyMap > Key-Binding Filter filters empty.)
I checked python console log and it shows nothing.
any blender console mode something like Maya's mel script editor's History > Echo All commands
?

If you switch to the Scripting workspace the info panel shows most operators running as you use them. If you want every single one to show then you have to enable show all operators.
